# Code not executed after running script with "Run" function but directly from console it works

Tags: macos, console, rstudio

I am using R Studio (Version 2023.06.1+524) with macOS Monterey 12.1 and I am recently experiencing a problem with running parts of my script with the "Run" function.

When I try to run the code with the "Run" function, nothing happens and the code is not executed. When I copy the script and directly execute it in the console, everything is working and the code is executed.

Weirdly, some parts of my script are executed with the "Run" function without any issues. The part in question has been working before with the "Run" function as well, but suddenly it stopped working. I already tried a restart but this did not help.

Any suggestions highly appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance!